# WS-Federation authentication expiration time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cookies, authorization, ws-federation

I'm setting up WS-Federation with no identity and I can't figure out how to change the length of time for how long a user is authenticated for. I actually don't even know how long it takes for it to expire by default.

I tried setting the `ExpireTimeSpan` and `Cookie.Expiration` cookie options in my `ConfigureServices` method, but that gives me `HTTP ERROR 500`.
If I delete `TestAuthCookie` cookie while signed in, it's just recreated on the next authorized-only action without asking again for login.
I also attempted to use the `SignIn()` method in my controller because it has an `ExpiresUtc` option, but that didn't seem to do anything.

What I want is to expire authentication after 30 seconds of signing in. If the user attempts an authorized-only action after 30 seconds, they will require to sign in again.

**EDIT**: It appears that when I replace the scheme in my `SignIn` method with `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`, credentials do expire. However, when I click the Login button (or any action requiring to be authorized) the user is automatically logged in and cookie is recreated. But I want the user to be required to log in again.

Guide I used: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddWsFederation(options =>
    {
        options.Wtrealm = Configuration["wsfed:realm"];
        options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["wsfed:metadata"];
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "TestAuthCookie";
        //options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        //options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    });

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

Attempt at using SignIn method in controller action:

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    var personClaims = new List<Claim>()
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "PersonName"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "person@email.com")
    };

    var personIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(personClaims, "Person Identity");

    var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { personIdentity });

    return SignIn(userPrincipal,
        new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = "https://app:1234/",
            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30)
        }, WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this method for generating cookie

```
  public void GenerateCookie(HttpResponse response, string name, string token)
    {
        try
        {
            int timeToLiveCookie = 0;
            TimeSpan timeSpanToAdd = default(TimeSpan);
            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions();
            cookieOptions.Path = "/";
            cookieOptions.HttpOnly = false;

            cookieOptions.Expires = currentDate.AddYears(10);
            response.Cookies.Append(name, token, cookieOptions);             

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response alex, but I already have a cookie being generated. I was hoping there's a more "official" way to expire authentication within the WS-Federation setup I have. I just don't see how generating another cookie would help me here. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here?